# Define instance attribute to store one of the two "constant" class attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still trying to understand how I can create an instance attribute on **Employment_status** to **store** one of the two constant attributes such as RESIGNED or CURRENT_EMPLOYEE.

So, when I defined my two constant class attributes, I can make my constructor to look like *Employee(Employment_status, name, surname, number)*. The employment_status would take the argument from the Employment Status to change either "RESIGNED" or "CURRENT_EMPLOYEE", when the code is executed.

I have tried to performed my own coding, and would like to know if I am on the right track.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, number):
    self.name = name
    self.surname = surname
    self.number = number


class Employee(Person):

    #class attribute
    def employment_status(object):
        employment_status = "CURRENT_EMPLOYEE"
        employment_status = "RESIGNED"

    #instance attributes
    def __init__(self, name, surname, number,employment_status):
        super().__init__(self,name,surname,number)
        self._employment_status = employment_status
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do in the `employment_status()` function. You're assigning a local variable that you never use, and you're assigning it with different values.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent assigning an employment status that isn't one of those two constants?

Comment: Hi, I am looking to assign the employment_status as PERMANENT or CURRENT_EMPLOYEEE, knowing that "Permanent" or "Current_Employee" would be used when I do my test client.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` looks OK, assuming an `Employee` simply adds an employment status  to a `Person`.

It looks like it lays the ground work for `employment_status` to be a `property`, though, rather than an ordinary method.

```
@property
def employment_status(self):
    return self._employment_status

@employment_status.setter
def employment_status(self, status):
    if status not in ["CURRENT_EMPLOYEE", "RESIGNED"]:
        raise ValueError("Invalid status: {}".format(status))
    self._employment_status = status
```

Then you can get an employee's status:

```
>>> e = Employee("bob", "smith", 1, "CURRENT_EMPLOYEE")
>>> e.employment_status
"CURRENT_EMPLOYEE"
```

or change it

```
>>> e.employment_status = "RESIGNED"
>>> e.employment_status
"RESIGNED"
>>> e.employment_status = "foo"  # raises an exception
>>> e.employement_status
"RESIGNED"   # unchanged
```

Note that `__init__` should use the setter as well, instead of assigning directly to `_employment_status`:

```
def __init__(self, name, surname, number,employment_status):
    super().__init__(self, name, surname, number)
    # not self._employment_status = ...
    self.employment_status = employment_status
```

Comment: I'm not really sure that's what he's asking about. I think he may be looking for something equivalent to C `enum`.

Comment: My updated setter moves in that direction, though something more could obviously be done.

Comment: The `__init__` method should use the new setter instead of assigning to `self._employment_status`.